# Assign specific value and a specific name to a factor level

Tags: r, r-factor

Is it possible to assign a specific value and a specific name to a factor level?

For example: I have a factor with more than 300 regional values (with a specific 5-digit regional code and the name of the region)

With `as.numeric(substr(region, 1, 5))` I get a new numeric variable with the regional code.

It works fine, but I already have a huge dataset (without `data.table` it wouldn't work) and there are some other variables, where I also need a specific code and the name.

Ist there a way to put the code number and the name in one factor (or another sort of column)?

Edit: Example of columns (the first 4 and the last 4 - imported from SPSS)

```
1002  KS Kiel                                             
1003  KS Luebeck 
1051  Dithmarschen                                    
1053  Herzogtum Lauenburg 
.
.
.                                
16073  Saalfeld-Rudolstadt 
16074  Saale-Holzland-Kreis, KS Jena                               
16075  Saale-Orla-Kreis, Greiz 
16077  Altenburger Land
```

And now I also want to address only the code numbers (1002 - 16077) to create some  regional aggregations.

Comment: it is not completely clear to me what you want, can you show example data and an example required output?